# Setting up Ember-Data DS.RESTadapter with Wordpress and JSON REST API Plugin

Tags: wordpress, ember.js, ember-data

I'm just getting started with ember, and working on an ember.js app which loads it's data store from a Wordpress blog, which is running the [JSON REST API](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API) plugin.

The API has a namespace of 'wp-json.php', and uses these [conventions](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/master/docs/guides/working-with-posts.md).

**Issue I:**
I'm getting the error `Error while loading route` once I try to setup the DS.RESTAdapter, and load the model.

**Issue II:**
I'm trying to pass the header `"type": "custom_post_type_slug"`, in order to get the data of a [custom post type](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/master/docs/guides/working-with-posts.md#collection-views), and can't get that to work either.

Here is my code:

```
    App = Ember.Application.create({ }); //Create App

    //Router
    App.Router.map(function () { 

  
  
           this.resource('posts', {path: '/'},  function() {
  
    
                this.resource('post', { path: ':post_id' } );
  
                 });
   
   
  
       }); //End Router




    //Posts Route 
    App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

       model: function(){
           return this.store.find('post');
    
    
       },

    
     });




   //Data

   App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
      title         : DS.attr('string'),
  
});




   App.PostAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
      host: 'http://example.com',
      namespace: 'wp-json.php'
   });


    DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
      headers: {
       "type": "custom_post_type_slug"
 
       }
     });
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The full error I'm getting is: `[Debug] Transition #1: posts: handling error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'factory.store = this') (ember.prod.js, line 3078)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, after much head bashing and reading, I solved these two issues as follows:

**ISSUE I:**

This issue was related to the format of my JSON being returned. The json was being returned as:

```
[{"id":963,"title":"Joe Whitney"},{"id":962,"title":"Philip Varone"}]
```

Instead of being prefixed by `"posts"` as ember.js expects, like so:

```
{"posts" : [{"id":963,"title":"Joe Whitney"},{"id":962,"title":"Philip Varone"}]}
```

Once I modified the plugin to return the JSON in the format ember expected, I resolved this issue.

**ISSUE 2:**
I was improperly trying to pass the query `"type": "custom_post_type_slug"` via the RESTAdapter headers, instead of via the DS.Store find method. I solved this by following the [DS.Store find method guidelines](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_find) and instead passing the query variables through the model declaration like so:

```
//Posts Route 
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

   model: function(){
       return this.store.find('post', {'type' : 'custom_post_type_slug'});


   },


 });
```

Comment: For updating the WP-API's JSON return I added `$result = array('posts' => $result);` at line 261 in class-wp-json-server.php (not sure if this is what Nate did or not but worked for me).

In addition to what Nate has, to get this to work with the latest WP-API plugin I had to also specify the primaryKey like so:

`App.PostSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({primaryKey: 'ID'});`

Comment: @Styledev – I updated the JSON return similarly around line 261 also, but created a conditional, so that single post queries return without the 'posts'. I actually also modified the WP-API code to return the ID as 'id' instead of 'ID', however your solution using a Serializer is much slicker.

Comment: What was the conditional that you used?

Comment: Mine is actually fairly hacked together: `if($result[0] == '[' ) { echo '{"posts":' . $result . '}'; } else { echo $result; };` but i suppose you could work that easily in with your `$results = array(...);` method.